# args[0] always contains full path when running in GDB

Tags: c++, c, gdb

When I run execute normally (without GDB), the args[0] is what I entered on the command prompt.
But when I run using GDB, it includes full path.
Is there any way to GDB to set args[0] same as command prompt?

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// defining main with arguments
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        printf("You have entered %d arguments:\n", argc);

        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Stand alone:

```
./a.out
You have entered 1 arguments:
./a.out
```

With GDB:

```
gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.el7
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/prasads/./a.out
You have entered 1 arguments:
/home/prasads/./a.out
```

Is there a way without having to change the code that I can get GDB to same output as command prompt?

Comment: Why do you care? The user might copy, rename or symlink your executable.

Comment: Why is that important?

Comment: This is just a sample program. the real program is using the expecting args[0] to be simple string not a path and is using it to create folder with the name as args[0].

Comment: Okay, the program *is doing* that. That does not explain *why* it is doing that. IMHO the assumption under which this development was made is incorrect. And it won't become better just because there is (maybe) a way to make GCC compatible to your app. You should think on how to make your app compatible with GCC instead.

Comment: @user2043396 *The real program is using the expecting args[0] to be simple string not a path* -- You should have initially written the code to get the filename from the string being sent to you.  Then it wouldn't have mattered what compiler was used.

Comment: The user can not only run `./a.out`, but also `../prasads/a.out` or `../../home/prasads/a.out` or `~/a.out` or `/home/prasads/a.out`. That's how Linux (and Windows as well) works. Adapt your program to reality.

Comment: You might be interested in [`basename(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html). But be aware it's possible to run a program and give it an `argv[0]` that's completely unrelated to the program's filename...

Comment: The executable is not being called directly; it is called in shell script which does other things like sets ENV variables, PATH variable etc. and then finally calls the executable with only exeName without the path.

Comment: @user2043396 *The executable is not being called directly*  Today, that's true.  What about future changes?  You now know expecting any specific value for `argv[0]` has no basis - your program can get effectively any value for `argv[0]`

Comment: What `argv[0]` contains is not standardized nor guaranteed. It is possible to launch a program (via the `exec` family of functions, and by other means as well) where `argv[0]` is an arbitrary string or even empty or not present at all (`argc` being `0` is possible). Don't rely on `argv[0]` for anything important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way without having to change the code that I can get GDB to same output as command prompt?

Yes: you can use [exec-wrapper](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html) to set `argv[0]` to anything you want.

**Update:**

> exec-wrapper seems to be used for setting env variables; Not sure how I can use exec-wrapper to change argv[0]

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (int j = 0; j < argc; ++j) printf("%d: %s\n", j, argv[j]);
  return 0;
}

gcc echo-argv.c -o echo-argv
gdb --batch -ex run --args ./echo-argv foo bar baz

0: /tmp/echo-argv
1: foo
2: bar
3: baz
[Inferior 1 (process 3580209) exited normally]

cat wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash

exec -a "xxx" "$@"

gdb --batch -ex 'set exec-wrapper ./wrapper.sh' -ex run --args ./echo-argv foo bar baz

0: xxx
1: foo
2: bar
3: baz
[Inferior 1 (process 3580521) exited normally]
```

Replace `xxx` with `./a.out` or whatever else you want.

P.S. This [GDB bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15415) may also be relevant here.

Comment: exec-wrapper seems to be used for setting env variables; Not sure how I can use exec-wrapper to change argv[0]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `C`, `C++`, or any other language. This is an artifact of the way the operating system works. All modern operating systems that I know anything about, both Unix-like and Windows, require the creator of a new process to provide the information that may be provided to the new process as its argument vector. This includes what becomes `argv[0]`. The parent process can specify anything it pleases in this field, including random junk or nothing at all. Whether the field will contain a full path or a relative path will vary depending on what the programmer felt like doing when they wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> The executable is not being called directly; it is called in shell script which does other things like sets ENV variables, PATH variable etc. and then finally calls the executable with only exeName without the path.

That being the case, instead of trying to force gdb to do what you want, you should use the `basename` function which strips off any leading path elements from a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        printf("You have entered %d arguments:\n", argc);

        printf("%s\n", basename(argv[0]));
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
                printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ /home/dbush/x1 a b c
You have entered 4 arguments:
x1
a
b
c
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$
```

Answer (score -1):

When you run the program using GDB, GDB by default will use the absolute path to the executable.

If you really want `GDB` to display the relative path of your program you can run **(inside GDB)**

```
cd /path/to/dir
run ./out
```

and it will run it but now the `argc` will be equal to `2` and the second argument will be the one you desire.

Comment: Okay, this explains what happens, but it doesn't answer OPs question.

Comment: GDB certainly does know current working directory.

Comment: I didn't know, edited.

Comment: If cd before run didn't help and for some reason there is a use case where you want to check that program started exactly like expected from relative path and name.
You can add probably breakpoint at start of main, and edit argv from gdb (in the worst case scenario probably).  

set variable argv[0] = "./a.out"

Then write c to continue debuging.