# Different RSP register value between Radare2 and GDB

Tags: gdb, cpu-registers, radare2

the question is, as the title states, I'm getting a different `rsp` value when I try to read the `rsp` register after hitting the breakpoint of a particular function.

I think from my research, commands between `Radare2` and `GDB` are equivalent, but it seems they are not since `Radare2` is giving me the wrong value. I'm trying to understand the cause of this difference, so if anyone can give me an idea, I would appreciate it.

---

Since `GDB` is giving me the right values, I will first show how I work with `GDB`:

```
» gdb ./test
pwndbg> b *&(fun)
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40117d: file src/test.c, line 10.
pwndbg> r
pwndbg> i r $rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffcd28      0x7fffffffcd28
pwndbg> p &buffer[0]
$1 = 0x7fffffffcca0 ""
```

---

Now, here is my attempt at trying to do equivalent commands of the above with `Radare2` (I'm trying to learn how to use `Radare2` better)

```
» r2 -d ./test
[0x7ffff7fd3090]> aaa
INFO: Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
INFO: Analyze imports (af@@@i)
INFO: Analyze entrypoint (af@ entry0)
INFO: Analyze symbols (af@@@s)
INFO: Recovering variables
INFO: Analyze all functions arguments/locals (afva@@@F)
...
[0x7ffff7fd3090]> afl | grep fun
0x0040117d    1     63 dbg.fun
[0x7ffff7fd3090]> db dbg.fun
[0x7ffff7fd3090]> s 0x40117d
[0x0040117d]> dc
INFO: hit breakpoint at: 0x40117d
[0x0040117d]> afv
var char[128] buffer @ rbp-0x80
[0x0040117d]> dr rsp
0x7fffffffcdc8 <---- this should be 0x7fffffffcd28 
[0x0040117d]> x/16x @rbp-0x80
- offset -      6061 6263 6465 6667 6869 6A6B 6C6D 6E6F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x7fffffffcd60  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  

# 0x7fffffffcd60 should be 0x7fffffffcca0
................
```

---

In summary,

`0x7fffffffcdc8 (R2) != 0x7fffffffcd28 (GDB)`

and

`0x7fffffffcd60 (R2) != 0x7fffffffcca0 (GDB)`

Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong in the `Radare2`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Radare2 is giving me the wrong value.

What makes you think one value is right and the other is wrong?

When a Linux process starts, the kernel places a bunch of data at the top of the stack (which in turn affects the value of `RSP` when `_start` is invoked), and that data can vary in size.

One of the things placed on the stack is the `argv[]` vector, and GDB has a [tendency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76416432/50617) to invoke the program being debugged as `/absolute/path/to/./test`.

If `Radare2` doesn't do that, this could easily explain the difference of 160 bytes.